# ruby .dat file splitting

Tags: ruby, file

i am new in ruby, and i have trouble solving a problem. I have a large stream file File.dat, and all i know about it, is its structure.

it begins with

Numeric - 3 characters

Numeric - 10 characters

Numeric - 2 characters

Numeric - 12 characters

Alphanumeric - 30 characters

i need to cut it (this described beginning) into 5 variables to be able to work with it. so far i was only able to do it with a txt file, but it doesn't work on the .dat file

```
file = File.open("file.txt", 'r')
while !file.eof?    
   line = file.readline    
end    
   var1 = line[0..2]    
   var2 = line[3..12]    
   var3 = line[13..14]    
   var4 = line[15..26]    
   var5 = line[27..56]    
puts var1
```

Comment: What is the difference between the txt file and the dat file? Is it just the contents or is your dat file something else like a named pipe? What is the output of your program? And the expected output?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Is it a binary file?  If not, what do you know about its character encoding?  You might try reading a few bytes at a time if you're confident about the fixed length of the fields.  Check out [IO#read](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-i-read) and [IO.binread](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-c-binread)

Comment: The file is a binary stream file, (hope i understand it correctly) a named pipe. about the output of the program, there is none, i just need to cut it up into variables or an array. I added the code for the text file to show what i need on a basic (txt) file

Answer (score 0):

In your example you are using .txt extension, but you should use .dat.
Try this one:

`line = File.open('file.dat', File::RDONLY){|f| f.read }`

Comment: as i was saying, i was only able to do it with a txt file, but it doesn't work on the .dat file.